# Flutter The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im having an error stating "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')." Ive tried to add the '!' mark as stated and searching online but it doesn't resolve the issue. any ideas?

```
factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserModel(
      name: snapshot.data()["name"],
      email: snapshot.data()['email'],
      phoneNumber: snapshot.data()['phoneNumber'],
      uid: snapshot.data()['uid'],
      isOnline: snapshot.data()['isOnline'],
      profileUrl: snapshot.data()['profileUrl'],
      status: snapshot.data()['status'],
      designation: snapshot.data()['designation'],
      company: snapshot.data()['company'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because if `snapshot.data()` is `null` then you can't really access its fields, try `null` checking it :

```dart
snapshot.data()?['name'] ?? ''
```

And according to [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) `data` method returns non-null map, so you can try also this :

```dart
(snapshot.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)['name']
```

Always assuming you allow `null` values for name parameter. Otherwise you will need to null check it also

```dart
(snapshot.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)['name'] ?? ''
```

Comment: hi, now the error occurs at the name

Comment: Which name you mean?

Comment: the [ 'name' ] has this error 'The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.'

Comment: You can try `(snapshot.data() as Map<String,dynamic>?) ['name'] ?? ''`

Comment: still doesn't work but removing the '?' after dynamic works. does removing the '?' affects anything?

Comment: According to docs, `data` method of `DocumentSnapshot` returns non-null map, so yes you can remove `?`.

Comment: alright thank you so much!!! however, do i need the " ?? ' ' " no error occurs when i remove them as well

Comment: Editted the answer including all instructions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set type to your builder
2. make variable and assign `snapshot.data` with `!`
3. use variable without any `?`, `!`. Simple as List with `[]`

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Orders>>(                         // 1
   future: futureOrders,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
         return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
         final List<Orders> orders = snapshot.data!; // 2
         return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: orders.length,                // 3
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => _cartItemWidget(
               id: orders[index].id,                 // 3
               cost: orders[index].cost,             // 3
               date: orders[index].createdAt));      // 3
      }
   },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserModel(
      name: snapshot.data()["name"] ?? "",
      email: snapshot.data()['email'] ?? "",
      phoneNumber: snapshot.data()['phoneNumber'] ?? 0,
      uid: snapshot.data()['uid'] ?? 0,
      isOnline: snapshot.data()['isOnline'] ?? false,
      profileUrl: snapshot.data()['profileUrl'] ?? ""
    );
  }
```

Comment: hi, the error still exists